# How to determine temporal land cover change using two rasters? (From-to)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, change-detection

**ArcMap.** I am having trouble finding the correct method.

I want to end up with what is essentially a confusion matrix showing what each class from the **before** image converted to in the **after** image. I am wanting to create a transition graph like below:
[image]

I currently have two rasters with  **five** qualitative values. Do I need to reclassify the rasters to give them an arbitrary integer value? Would I then need to use the raster calculator? How would I interpret the result?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. I believe your raster has already integer values and maybe an associated Raster Attribute table with the qualitative value. If you don't care about the spatial dimension (where each change occurred), one possible solution is count the values for each class per raster and then compare the totals. A Raster Table contains the number of pixels for each class.

Comment: Many will laugh at me for this (maybe rightly so, but if it works is really wrong?), but depending on the size of the raster datasets, you may be able to convert them to polygons ("Raster to Polygon", do not simplify). The two resulting polygon feature classes could then be fed to "Tabulate Intersection" to get a table summarizing how the zones overlap